# Adding a constant to a slice of array

Tags: numpy, slice

Trying to mutate a slice of an array, adding a constant to elements with odd indices. But this must be a copy, not the original array which is assigned, since this doesn't change the array:

```
times = np.arange(10)
times[1::2] = times[1::2] + 0.5
```

It's curious since this works:

```
times[1::2] = -1
```

Why is the slice a copy?
How to make it work like expected?

Comment: If you'd tried `times[1::2] += .5` you'd have gotten  a UFuncTypeError complaining about mixing floats and ints.

Comment: @hpaulj: Correct, this makes `times[1::2] += .5` and `times[1::2] = times[1::2] + .5` having a different error handling.

Comment: Yes, the array assignment `x[....] = ...` usually casts the values silently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use addition assignment (with type agreement):

```
a = np.arange(10).astype(float)
a[1::2] += 0.5
```

---

```
array([0. , 1.5, 2. , 3.5, 4. , 5.5, 6. , 7.5, 8. , 9.5])
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that adding `0.5` changes the dtype from int to float, and when you try to copy it back on the slice `times[1::2]` numpy will resolve the dtype incompatibility between the lhs and the rhs of `times[1::2] = times[1::2] + 0.5` by turning the slice into a copy instead of a view.

Check

```py
times = np.arange(10, dtype=float)
times[1::2] = times[1::2] + 0.5
#times = array([0. , 1.5, 2. , 3.5, 4. , 5.5, 6. , 7.5, 8. , 9.5])
```

casting the initial array as float lifts the dtype mismatch and numpy now slices into a view, and the change is propagated back into `times`.

See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html for details